# Font-awesome icons turning to garbage in .liquid files

Tags: shopify, font-awesome

I am attempting to use font awesome with Shopify and less.  I compile my less file into css and the following icon is added.

```
.icon-caret-down:before {
  content: "\f0d7";
}
```

I then rename my css file to css.liquid and upload it.  When I attempt to see the icon in firefox it comes out as garbage.  What should I be putting in my liquid file so that it doesn’t get turned into garbage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using font awesome with my site and the only part I changed was the top of the file to add the asset_url filter to the less file. See if that helps. Here's what it looks like:

```
@fontAwesomePath: '../font';

@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('{{ "fontawesome-webfont.eot" | asset_url }}');
  src: url('{{ "fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix" | asset_url }}') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('{{ "fontawesome-webfont.woff | asset_url }}') format('woff'),
    url('{{ "fontawesome-webfont.ttf" | asset_url }}') format('truetype'),
    url('{{ "fontawesome-webfont.svg#FontAwesome" | asset_url }}') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```